# What is the meaning of "Midnight Guard - First Watch" and "Morning Guard - Third Watch" in the Zmanim

Tags: halacha, zemanim, evening-night

I have searched this Mi Yodea site extensively and can find no references. I am almost positive that this is not a duplicate, or answered somewhere else.Thank you.

I use the Halachic Times App (Halachic Times by Moshe Waisberg {developer pnemonic@gmail.com})

I have written to the developer and asked the question on the APP itself., and received no answer from him

The exact sequence is: Twilight; Nightfall; Midnight Guard-First Watch; Midnight; Morning Guard-Third Watch.
Sunrise, and the earliest time for SHEMA are given;

MY QUESTION: (While interesting) HOW, and WHY, are these times relevant to us today; and WHY do we need to know them?

Comment: Isn't there something in Talmud Brachot that relates this to shifts that were at the Bet Hamikdash?

Comment: @DanF [It's on Berakhot 3a, but my related comment was deleted]

Comment: @DanF  thank you was most helpful to my understanding of these Zmanim

Comment: @Kazibácsi Since you located it, why not summarize and post as an answer?

Comment: @DanF There's an accepted answer 'וגו

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be referring to when the angels in heaven switch guard posts, which is a time when heaven is very open to accept tefilos on the chorban beis hamikdash and the galus. This happens at every third of the night.

Source: Shulchan Aruch, Simon Aleph, Siph Beis.